# Navigation Component Android NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

Please help me, I have some problems with the navigation directions method from the navigation component Android. The Error is

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method actionCompleteRegister(...

For the complete log error like this:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method actionCompleteRegister(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroidx/navigation/NavDirections; in class Lcom/fdbr/auth/ui/verify/VerifyFragmentDirections$Companion; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.fdbr.auth.ui.verify.VerifyFragmentDirections$Companion' appears in /data/app/com.fdbr.android.debug-1/base.apk:classes9.dex)
        at com.fdbr.auth.ui.verify.VerifyFragment.redirectUserToCompleteData(VerifyFragment.kt:493)
        at com.fdbr.auth.ui.verify.VerifyFragment.access$redirectUserToCompleteData(VerifyFragment.kt:45)
        at com.fdbr.auth.ui.verify.VerifyFragment$observer$3.onChanged(VerifyFragment.kt:342)
        at com.fdbr.auth.ui.verify.VerifyFragment$observer$3.onChanged(VerifyFragment.kt:45)
        at com.fdbr.android.util.extensions.FreshObserver.onChanged(FreshObserver.kt:16)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:131)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:149)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:307)
        at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
        at androidx.lifecycle.Transformations$2$1.onChanged(Transformations.java:155)
        at androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData$Source.onChanged(MediatorLiveData.java:152)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:131)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:149)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:307)
        at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
        at com.fdbr.android.util.extensions.NetworkExtKt.isSuccess(NetworkExt.kt:33)
        at com.fdbr.android.business.repository.AuthRepository$verifyCode$$inlined$let$lambda$1.accept(AuthRepository.kt:175)
        at com.fdbr.android.business.repository.AuthRepository$verifyCode$$inlined$let$lambda$1.accept(AuthRepository.kt:27)
        at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onNext(LambdaObserver.java:63)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:201)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:255)
        at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:119)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

In Class VerifyFragmentDirections not found method actionCompleteRegister, I don't know why but it's only happened in OS Marshmellow and Nougat

I'm already implementing dependencies in app for the navigation component:

```
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'
}
```

If you have solution for my issue, please help me. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Change to newest version for all dependencies in gradle model helped for me

Answer (score 0):

**Make Sure the marked classpath is added in your project level build.gradle file or not.**

[image]